# Why does this camera rotation code snap back to where it started?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
        cameraVertical = Input.GetAxis("Camera Vertical");
        angle = cameraVertical;
        angle = angle + myCamera.transform.localRotation.x;
        myCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);
```

I am working on my first 3D game in unity and I created this player controller. The "Camera Vertical" axis is based off of mouse movement, and it seemingly starts to work before snapping back to 0,0,0 rotation. Can anyone help me figure out what is causing it?

I tried to think of possible fixes, but I could not think of anything. I was expecting it to rotate the camera up or down depending on mouse movement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a minimal reproducible example.  It'll be quite difficult to figure out the issue.  In the mean time, you could always debug what happens to the values, particularly the ```angle``` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`Quaternion`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) has not 3 but rather 4 components `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`**! That the names seems to match axes is just a "coincidence" / based on the underlying vector4 name mapping.

Others usually call the components `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` instead.

They all move in the range `-1` to `1` and are **not** the Euler space angles you expected!

⇒ If you don't know exactly what you are doing you **never** want to touch the components of a `Quaternion` directly!

Further you also will not want to use [`Quaternion.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) in your use case either, as there are many ways to represent a given Quaternion in Euler space and Unity will just pick a "best human readable" one.

> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the
> Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles.
> Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation
> using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite
> different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if
> you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
> See bottom scripting example for more information.
>
> To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with
> rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading
> .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a
> rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see
> the [Quaternion * operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html).

---

What happens in your case is:

- The `cameraVertical` directly read from an axis ranges within `-1` and `1`. And while not moving the mouse the it will be `0`.
- Then as mentioned above the `localRotation.x` and `angle` will also be a value within the range of `-1` to `1`.
- You apply this back treating it as an euler angle
- This euler angle in any case maximum lies in the range `-2` to `2`

=> In total you pretty much approximate the rotation to `0,0,0` in a couple of frames - it will never even move far apart from that.

---

What you want to rather do would be e.g.

```
cameraVertical = Input.GetAxis("Camera Vertical") * MULTIPLIER;
myCamera.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(cameraVertical, 0, 0);
```

- you get your axis
- you multiply by a certain multiplier depending on your use case (rotation sensitivity)
- then you add the new rotation on top of the already existing one using a Quaternion multiplication

Answer (score 1):

It's because localRotation.x is not an angle. It's component of Quaternion.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

I'm not sure, but I think thay you want to do something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera myCamera;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _currentPitchAngle;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _sensitivityPitch = 10f;

    private void Update()
    {
        _currentPitchAngle += Input.GetAxis("Camera Vertical") * _sensitivityPitch * Time.deltaTime;
        myCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_currentPitchAngle, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: a quaternion is literally used to represent rotation (an angle)

Comment: yes, but .x .y .z not a pitch, roll and yaw angles

Comment: @mushroomKnight a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) in general is a four component (thus the name) construct based on complex numbers (extending complex number space to be exact) .. (a,b,c,d in Unity map to x,y,z,w, this is mainly due to the fact that underlying they use a float4 the same type as for Vector4) .. it is not the same as EULER angles you are having in mind. There is many ways to represent a specific quaternion rotation in euler space, but the otherway round a given euler rotation has always the same quaternion value